# How to make api calls to get new data everytime when hit api endpoint

Tags: javascript, api

I have an API endpoint which returns me an object in JOSN format.
It does provide title and content properties from JSON.
I am using this result in my frontend.
I have a button in UI, upon clicking the button it hits the API endpoint.
Response comes from API and displayed in frontend as usual.

Problem: It always return same result. But when i try hitting API in browser (using reload current page tab), it returns a different result on every new hit.

I tried looking on reloading the complete page.
But I think that would be an unnecessary thing to reload the complete page.

```
 <div id="main" role="main" class="page-content">
    <div class="quote-actions">
      <button class="next" type="button" onclick="getQuote()">Show me another</button>
    </div>

    <blockquote class="quote-content">
    </blockquote>
    <cite class="quote-citation">
      <span class="quote-book"></span>
      <span class="quote-author">A</span>
    </cite>
  </div>
```

```js
function randomize() {

  var url = 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1';

  // Use fetch() to make the request to the API
  fetch(url).then(function(result) {
      return result.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    var authorTag = document.getElementsByClassName("quote-author");
    var span = authorTag[0];
    span.textContent = json[0].title;
    console.log(span);

    var contentTag = document.getElementsByClassName("quote-content");
    span = contentTag[0];
    span.innerHTML = json[0].content;
    console.log(content);
  });
}

function getQuote() {
  randomize();
}
```

Goal: It should return new response everytime when onclick event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your ajax call is getting cached.  adding a datetime stamp at the end of the url in your ajax call will put an end to that.

```
var url = 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&' + new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch caches internally. Try `fetch(url, {cache: "no-cache"})`